# How to programmatically edit xorg.conf?

Tags: edit, xorg

I need to add Options to ServerLayout (creating ServerLayout if not present).

- How to do it properly?
- Are there tools that convert xorg.conf to xml and bacK?
- Are there other more programming-friendly configuration mechanisms apart of xorg.conf? (I can't find all options in `xset`)

There can be also xorg.conf.d, but it does not work on that system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out augeas. you can use this too parse configuration files using it and xorg.conf is one of them

http://augeas.net/

For xorg.conf, you can use the following lens as the one in your default installation is a bit buggy.
https://github.com/Mpounta/augeas/blob/master/lenses/xorg.aug